# how to add rows in datatable in for loop from a sql table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

I have a problem with my c# code in a asp.net website.

Here is my code.

```
mood = Session["feeling"].ToString();
DataTable dt2 = blrate.selectmood("selectmood", mood);
DataTable dt3=new DataTable();

for (int k = 0; k < dt2.Rows.Count; k++)
{
    dt3.Rows[k][0]= music.selectMusic("sel_musicname", Convert.toInt32(dt2.Rows[k][2]));
    dt3.Rows[k][1] = music.selectMusic("sel_musicUrl", Convert.ToInt32(dt2.Rows[k][2]));
}
GridView1.DataSource = dt3;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I want to add rows in datatable but it has the eror

> There is no row in position 0.

Final datatable must have two columns and k rows.
what should i do???

Comment: This is because your dt2.Rows.Count=0. Use debugger and check the value of dt2.Rows.Count

Comment: no it is not Empty. dt2.rows.Count is not 0.

Comment: Where do you define the columns of the dt3? And if you don't create a row for the dt3 they don't magically appear in dt3 rows collection just because you assign a value to an inexistant row

Comment: I want to create the columns of dt3 after select data from sqlserver.

Comment: Please, before going this far in your coding, try to understand some basic concepts. You cannot add data to a datatable if you haven't defined its structure (I mean its columns and each column with a name and type, eventually size and precision)

Comment: Thanks,you right. I understand my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Create columns (data you want to store) for `dt3` like (`dt3.Columns.Add(ColumnName)`. 
Then create row for datatable(dt3) like

```
for (int k = 0; k < dt2.Rows.Count; k++)
{
      DataRow row = dt3.NewRow();
      row[0]= music.selectMusic("sel_musicname", Convert.ToInt32(dt2.Rows[k][2]));
      row[1] = music.selectMusic("sel_musicUrl", Convert.ToInt32(dt2.Rows[k][2]));

      dt3.Rows.Add(row);
}

    GridView1.DataSource = dt3;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I try that but it has eror : Cannot find column 0.

Comment: Did you create columns in dt3 ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case `dt3` is just a DataTable with no rows and columns, So you need to assign Columns first then Add Rows through iterating the Previous table. Now consider the following code and Try:

```
DataTable dt2 = blrate.selectmood("selectmood", mood);
DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
dt3.Columns.Add("sel_musicname");
dt3.Columns.Add("sel_musicUrl");
for (int k = 0; k < dt2.Rows.Count; k++)
{
    DataRow dRow = dt3.NewRow();
    dRow[0] = music.selectMusic("sel_musicname", Convert.toInt32(dt2.Rows[k][2]));
    dRow[1] = music.selectMusic("sel_musicUrl", Convert.ToInt32(dt2.Rows[k][2]));
    dt3.Rows.Add(dRow);
}
GridView1.DataSource = dt3;
```